# Kendo UI Angular 2 Dialog component crashes the browser

Tags: angular, zone, kendo-ui-angular2

Kendo UI Angular 2 Dialog component affects Chrome and IE performance, both crash. Memory utilization grows very fast. 
May be there is a conflict with zone.js?

```
<kendo-dialog title="Awesome title">
  No need for content, look at the awesome title!
</kendo-dialog>
```

Here is my updated package.json:

```
"@angular/common": "2.2.3",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
"@angular/core": "2.2.3",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
"@angular/http": "2.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.2.3",
"@angular/router": "3.2.3",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.2.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.14.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^0.12.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.6.2",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.1.7",
"@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.27.0",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
"@types/filesaver": "0.0.30",
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/rx-dom": "^2.5.16",
"angular2-tree-component": "^2.3.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"file-saver": "^1.3.3",
"lodash": "^4.17.2",
"materialize-css": "^0.97.7",
"primeng": "^1.0.0-rc.6",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"rx-dom-events": "^7.0.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.41",
"typescript": "^2.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.26"
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a plunkr, that we can look at?

Comment: I'll try. Not sure about dependencies.

Comment: you can go to the kendo ui site and just open any demo in plunkr, so  all dependencies are set.

Comment: Can't set up my lib versions on plunkr, there is no package.json file

Comment: Here is a plunkr with a Dialog: http://plnkr.co/edit/It0AASw64CY9LD7zXPSQ?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've updated package.json, reinstall all libraries. The problem with control still remains. Another controls, in instance grid, or angular 2 features working well.

Comment: can you share a github link to a project where the issue can be reproduced? Or any link?